# The application variable in ASP.net(c#).

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, application-state

I have a problem with the application state in Asp.net. I need a list of Strings that i would use in different forms in the same application. Here I add the list:

```
Application.Add("users", new List<String>());
```

In a new form I try to add a string to the list, but I get NullReferenceException in the second line of the code below.

```
 List<String> ls=(List<String>) Application.Get("users");
            ls.Add(TextBox4.Text);
```

Comment: Please add some more code, like where EXACTLY do you add the list to the Application object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first slot of code the string is empty because of `{new List<String>()}`. You need to add the string in the list. Only after that, call the Application variable in another form to avoid the `NullReferenceException` Exception.

Comment: Correct, need to add { } after the constructor parenthesis.